# c++ bit-shift right unexpected result

Tags: c++, bit-shift

my code

```
int p = 85;
std::cout << std::hex << p << std::endl;
std::cout << (p >> 1) << ' ' << (p >> 2) << std::endl;
```

output:

```
0x55  // corrent!


0x2a 0x15  // the hell is this??
```

Anyone can explain this weird behaviour?

`(0x55 >> 1)` I expect to be `0x5`

`(0x55 >> 2)` I expect to be `0x0`

Comment: What do you expect and why?

Comment: Can you explain what you were expecting and why?

Comment: Can you explain what you meant by "weird"?

Comment: Write out the bits. The result is correct.

Comment: appended my expectations

Comment: 0x5 is 4 bits, 0x55 is 8 bits but you shift on 1 bit and 2 bits.

Comment: ah... my bad! thank you guys; this topic can be closed now xD

Comment: This is the equivalent of `std::cout << (p / 2) << ' ' << (p / 4) << std::endl;`

Comment: Your expectations are incorrect. ``(0x55 >> 1)` I expect to be 0x5': well you should have expected `0x2a`. You are shifting by 1 bit, not 4.  Similarly for the other value.

Answer (score 4):

> can explain this weird behaviour?

Yes, you are right shifting 1 and 2 bits from `0b1010101`.

It'll be clearer if you look at the binary representation:

```cpp
#include <format>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int p = 85;
    std::cout << std::format("{:8b}\n{:8b}\n{:8b}\n", p, p >> 1, p >> 2);
}
```

Output:

```
 1010101
  101010
   10101
```

> `(0x55 >> 1)` I expect to be `0x5`
> `(0x55 >> 2)` I expect to be `0x0`

To shift in nibble (4 bits) sized steps, you would need to multiply by 4. That is, the above would need right shifting 4 and 8 bits respectively.